# How to use gke-boot-disk=pd-ssd disk with GKE Autopilot?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, autopilot

Autopilot makes all decisions about the nodes but, why are all nodes being created with `cloud.google.com/gke-boot-disk=pd-standard`? Is it possible to all nodes be created with ssd disk? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/ssd-pd
will that help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Autopilot managed node does not use SSD as the boot device, it doesn't support local SSD either. This behavior is not amendable.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  SSD is not currently supported by Autopilot.  We are looking at enabling this capability later this year.

Comment: @GariSingh sorry to bother you again: will the cluster need to be recreated when this feature is released? Is there an ETA for the release?

Comment: You will not need to recreate the cluster, but we won't be able to automatically migrate data stored on local disk to new nodes with SSD enabled.   No ETA yet, although we are hoping to release the feature before the middle of the year.